# Virtual Environment Pylons Version

Tags: python, installation, pylons

I am trying to install an application (on Fedora) made by another member of our web dev team some time ago. Ive managed to configure almost everything I need to in my virtual environment, but when I try the shell command:

```
python setup.py install
```

It points to a newer version of Pylons and I get the error:

```
error: Installed distribution Pylons 0.9.7 conflicts with requirement Pylons==0.10
```

I have uninstalled this virtual environments version of pylons using `pip uninstall` and reinstalled the correct version. Ive checked this by using:

```
python
Python 2.6 (r26:66714, Mar 15 2012, 10:33:52) 
[GCC 4.6.1 20110908 (Red Hat 4.6.1-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pylons
>>> pylons.__version__
'0.10'
>>>
```

So it looks as if it is still using the main system version of pylons? The program does use some company middleware, Ive tried uninstalling and reinstalling that, but the stack trace doesnt indicate such an error.

Here is the rest of the stack trace:

```
[~/workspace/PYTHON/shipping] python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to shipping.egg-info/requires.txt
writing shipping.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to shipping.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to shipping.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to shipping.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing paster_plugins to shipping.egg-info/paster_plugins.txt
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'shipping.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers
copying build/lib/shipping/controllers/recipients.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers
copying build/lib/shipping/controllers/error.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers
copying build/lib/shipping/controllers/forms.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers
copying build/lib/shipping/controllers/security.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers
copying build/lib/shipping/controllers/pallets.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers
copying build/lib/shipping/controllers/licences.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers
copying build/lib/shipping/controllers/items.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers
copying build/lib/shipping/controllers/resources.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers
copying build/lib/shipping/controllers/descriptions.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers
copying build/lib/shipping/controllers/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers
copying build/lib/shipping/controllers/validators.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests
copying build/lib/shipping/tests/test_models.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional
copying build/lib/shipping/tests/functional/test_forms.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional
copying build/lib/shipping/tests/functional/test_items.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional
copying build/lib/shipping/tests/functional/test_descriptions.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional
copying build/lib/shipping/tests/functional/test_licences.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional
copying build/lib/shipping/tests/functional/test_item.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional
copying build/lib/shipping/tests/functional/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional
copying build/lib/shipping/tests/functional/test_shipform.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional
copying build/lib/shipping/tests/functional/test_pallets.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional
copying build/lib/shipping/tests/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/lib
copying build/lib/shipping/lib/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/lib
copying build/lib/shipping/lib/helpers.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/lib
copying build/lib/shipping/lib/base.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/lib
copying build/lib/shipping/lib/app_globals.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/lib
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/view.html -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/management
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/management/shippingFormTabs.htm -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/management
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/includes
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/includes/itemform.html -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/includes
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/includes/shippingform.html -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/includes
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/includes/authorisationform.html -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/includes
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/includes/printables
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/includes/printables/shippinginstructions.html -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/includes/printables
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/includes/printables/proformainvoice.html -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/includes/printables
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/includes/printables/collectionnote.html -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/includes/printables
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/includes/printables/hcletter.html -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/includes/printables
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/includes/printables/packinglist.html -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/includes/printables
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/includes/printables/base.html -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/includes/printables
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/includes/recipientform.html -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/includes
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/reports
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/reports/resources
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/reports/resources/GOTHICI.TTF -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/reports/resources
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/reports/resources/report.css -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/reports/resources
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/reports/resources/GOTHICB.TTF -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/reports/resources
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/reports/resources/letterhead.pdf -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/reports/resources
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/reports/resources/GOTHIC.TTF -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/reports/resources
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/reports/resources/GOTHICBI.TTF -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/reports/resources
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/reports/base.mako -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/reports
copying build/lib/shipping/templates/reports/shipping_instructions.mako -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/templates/reports
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/config
copying build/lib/shipping/config/middleware.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/config
copying build/lib/shipping/config/routing.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/config
copying build/lib/shipping/config/environment.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/config
copying build/lib/shipping/config/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/config
copying build/lib/shipping/config/deployment.ini_tmpl -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/config
copying build/lib/shipping/websetup.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping
copying build/lib/shipping/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/model
copying build/lib/shipping/model/workflow.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/model
copying build/lib/shipping/model/permission.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/model
copying build/lib/shipping/model/definitions.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/model
copying build/lib/shipping/model/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/model
copying build/lib/shipping/model/meta.py -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/model
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public
copying build/lib/shipping/public/pylons-logo.gif -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public
copying build/lib/shipping/public/Thumbs.db -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/inmarsat_scripts
copying build/lib/shipping/public/inmarsat_scripts/script.js -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/inmarsat_scripts
copying build/lib/shipping/public/inmarsat_scripts/shipping.js -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/inmarsat_scripts
copying build/lib/shipping/public/inmarsat_scripts/components.js -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/inmarsat_scripts
copying build/lib/shipping/public/favicon.ico -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/style_sheets
copying build/lib/shipping/public/style_sheets/componentsPage.css -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/style_sheets
copying build/lib/shipping/public/style_sheets/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/style_sheets
copying build/lib/shipping/public/style_sheets/requestsView.css -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/style_sheets
copying build/lib/shipping/public/style_sheets/components_IE.css -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/style_sheets
copying build/lib/shipping/public/style_sheets/shippingForm_Temp.css -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/style_sheets
copying build/lib/shipping/public/style_sheets/base.css -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/style_sheets
copying build/lib/shipping/public/style_sheets/ui.all.css -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/style_sheets
copying build/lib/shipping/public/style_sheets/highlight.css -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/style_sheets
copying build/lib/shipping/public/style_sheets/ie.css -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/style_sheets
copying build/lib/shipping/public/style_sheets/shippingForm.css -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/style_sheets
copying build/lib/shipping/public/style_sheets/components.css -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/style_sheets
copying build/lib/shipping/public/style_sheets/shippingForm_final.css -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public/style_sheets
copying build/lib/shipping/public/bg.png -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/public
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers/recipients.py to recipients.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers/error.py to error.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers/forms.py to forms.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers/security.py to security.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers/pallets.py to pallets.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers/licences.py to licences.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers/items.py to items.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers/resources.py to resources.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers/descriptions.py to descriptions.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/controllers/validators.py to validators.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/test_models.py to test_models.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional/test_forms.py to test_forms.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional/test_items.py to test_items.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional/test_descriptions.py to test_descriptions.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional/test_licences.py to test_licences.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional/test_item.py to test_item.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional/test_shipform.py to test_shipform.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/functional/test_pallets.py to test_pallets.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/tests/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/lib/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/lib/helpers.py to helpers.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/lib/base.py to base.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/lib/app_globals.py to app_globals.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/config/middleware.py to middleware.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/config/routing.py to routing.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/config/environment.py to environment.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/config/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/websetup.py to websetup.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/model/workflow.py to workflow.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/model/permission.py to permission.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/model/definitions.py to definitions.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/model/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/shipping/model/meta.py to meta.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying shipping.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying shipping.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying shipping.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying shipping.egg-info/entry_points.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying shipping.egg-info/not-zip-safe -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying shipping.egg-info/paster_plugins.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying shipping.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
copying shipping.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/EGG-INFO
creating 'dist/shipping-1.0.0dev_r2476-py2.6.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-i686/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-i686/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing shipping-1.0.0dev_r2476-py2.6.egg
removing '/home/aaron/workspace/shipenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/shipping-1.0.0dev_r2476-py2.6.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /home/aaron/workspace/shipenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/shipping-1.0.0dev_r2476-py2.6.egg
Extracting shipping-1.0.0dev_r2476-py2.6.egg to /home/aaron/workspace/shipenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages
Adding shipping 1.0.0dev-r2476 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/aaron/workspace/shipenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/shipping-1.0.0dev_r2476-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for shipping==1.0.0dev-r2476
error: Installed distribution Pylons 0.9.7 conflicts with requirement Pylons==0.10
(shipenv)
```

I noticed that in the stack trace it kept downloading and install Pylons 0.9.7 when I was trying to install it as the requirements in setup.py file were Pylons==0.9.7

But then this doesnt account for the conflict!

I managed to install the app by changing the requirements here, but then I get a different Pylons error (probably because its out of date)

**EDIT**

It looks like 0.9.7 is being installed because it is part of the requirements of a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

did you create the virtualenv with the --no-site-packages switch?

Comment: Yes, I did create it with no site packages.

Answer (score 0):

did you remember to activate the virtualenv?

```
source virtenv/bin/activate
```

before running the install

**edit:** you can also try to set the os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] to the virtenv/lib/site-packages

Comment: Yes I did, sorry! It got cut off in the copy but I am definitely in the virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Do a file search for Pylons 0.9.7 and check your $PATH as well.  There might be a version of Pylons 0.9.7 installed somewhere else which the script is referring to.